# Let $Y$ be a Geometric random variable, find the expected value of $e^{r(Y-1)}$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $Y$ be a Geometric random variable with $p\leq \frac{1}{2}$. I know that $f(y) = (1-p)^y p$ for $y=0,1,2,...$Therefore,

$$E(e^{r(Y-1)}) = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} e^{r(y-1)}(1-p)^yp$$

I want to calculate that expected value to prove that if $E(e^{r(Y-1)})=1$ then $r=\log(\frac{p}{1-p})$.

Going backwards from what I need to prove I get that
$$e^r\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right) = 1$$

Therefore I can say that $E(e^{r(Y-1)})$ should be $e^r\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)$ but I'm not aware of how to get there analytically. I would appreciate some advice in this one.

Comment: Write your sum as $\frac{p}{e^r}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}[e^r(1-p)]^y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, if $r = \log \frac{p}{1-p}$, then $$r(Y-1) = (Y-1) \log \frac{p}{1-p} = \log \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{Y-1},$$ hence $$e^{r(Y-1)} = \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{Y-1}.$$  It follows that $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[e^{r(Y-1)}] &= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{Y-1}\right] \\
&= \sum_{y=0}^\infty \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{y-1} (1-p)^y p \\
&= \sum_{y=0}^\infty p^y (1-p) \\
&= (1-p) \sum_{y=0}^\infty p^y \\
&= (1-p) \cdot \frac{1}{1-p} \\
&= 1. \end{align}$$

Or you can evaluate directly:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[e^{r(Y-1)}] 
&= \sum_{y=0}^\infty e^{r(y-1)} (1-p)^y p \\
&= \sum_{y=0}^\infty e^{ry} (1-p)^y e^{-r} p \\
&= e^{-r} p \sum_{y=0}^\infty (e^r (1-p))^y \\
&= e^{-r} p \frac{1}{1 - e^r (1-p)}.
\end{align}$$

Then we solve for $r$ such that this expression equals $1$; i.e.,
$$e^{-r} p = 1 - e^r (1-p).$$  Letting $u = e^r$, we get the quadratic
$$(1-p) u^2 - u + p = 0,$$ hence $$u \in \{1, p/(1-p)\}.$$  The first root gives $r = 0$ which we discard; the second root gives $r = \log \frac{p}{1-p}$ as claimed.

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have thought of the first approach you made to solve this problem. Thank you very much for your valuable answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the sum of infinite GP.
$$E(e^{r(1-y)})=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} e^{r(y-1)} (1-p)^y p=\frac{pe^{-r}}{1-e^{r(1-p)}} =1 \implies pe^{-r}=1-e^{r}(1-p).$$
$$\implies p=\frac{1-e^{-r}}{1-e^{-2r}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-r}} \implies e^{r}=\frac{p}{1-p}\implies r =\ln\frac{p}{1-p} $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now see where the Geometric Progression is but, at the beginning of your solution I think you missed a $Y$ and a $p$. So, the correction would be $E(e^{r(Y-1)}) = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty}e^{r(y-1)}(1-p)^yp$ at the first equality in your answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh! yes it was a typo, I have corrected them now.